# Is there any hook interface for replacing functions during compile time?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, logging, compilation

I need to track every log messages of some log level when the developer adds codes calling function log_message in C and C++.

This is for the log message management in the project to avoid too many developers adding too many messages in the source codes which do not follow the same conventions.

For example:

file1.c:

```
log_message("Module:Failed to create the file %s\n", file_name);
```

file2.c:

```
log_message("Failed to create the XXXX file %s\n", file_name);
```

MESSAGE_1000 is defined in another file message.h which is generated from our message database.
message.h:

```
const char* MESSAGE_1000 = “Module: Failed to create the file %s.\n”
```

After the file is precompiled:

file1.c becomes:

```
#include "message.h"
...
log_message(MESSAGE_1000，file_name)
```

file2.c becomes:

```
#include "message.h"
...
log_message(MESSAGE_1000，file_name)
```

When they need to add some new message to the log message database.

They can use a fixed name of function which can be recognized by the hook.

For example:

file1.c:

```
log_message_new("My new message:%s", message)
```

During compile:

message.h is updated to:

```
#defined MESSAGE_1001 "My new message:%s", message
```

In our message database, a new entry is added.

```
MESSAGE_1001="My new message:%s"
```

Why there is a message database? They are for the the non-developers. They can review all the log messages which may be seen by the customers.

Here I need a hook for catching and modifying the source codes.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: The answer will surely be different for C and C++. Please pick one.

Comment: Please show a hypothetical example of what you want. I don't understand your question. What do you mean with _"raw string instead of a string variable"_? It is always a variable, either literal variable or string variable.

Comment: Please make a [mcve] of the code you describe ("they are used to calling the log_message function") and show it.

Comment: What is a "string variable"? How does it differ from "raw string"?

Comment: In C++ I would think of std::string, in C "string variable" is a very unclear expression. Maybe deciding which language this is about would actually help.

Comment: `the message parameter has the fixed argument position` - why does it matter? You can save all. You don't provide a `vlog_message` function similar to `vprintf` that takes `va_list` as argument?

Comment: Not withstanding the upvotes on the question and the upvotes on an answer _it still not clear what you are asking_ so I propose to close the question.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, I added some more detailed examples.

Answer (score 2):

There is an option in gcc that is sometimes used for such cases. You can mock the function during link time with `-Wl,--wrap`, see [GNU ld linker options](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_3.html).

You will need a simple compilation unit:

```
extern "C" void __real_log_message(...);
extern "C" void __wrap_log_message(...) { 
      .... // do something with the arguments
      __real_log_message(...); // call real function
}
```

Add those symbols to your linking process and provide `-Wl,--wrap=log_message` linking option and you are good to go.